# sql from and to date range

Tags: mysql, sql

trying to get data between these date ranges but keeps throwing syntax error:

> syntax to use near '<='2016-01-06'))

```
Select user_email
from wp_users
where ID in (
        select user_id
        from wp_usermeta
        where (
                wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_login'
                and CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value As DATE) >= '2000-01-06'
                and <= '2016-01-06'
                )
        )
```

Comment: Also, take a look at joins.

Answer (score 2):

You're either thinking of using `BETWEEN` or you're missing a condition for your `<=` evaluation.

Try:

```
SELECT user_email
FROM wp_users
WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM wp_usermeta
        WHERE (
                wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_login'
                AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2000-01-06'
                AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS DATE) <= '2016-01-06'
                )
        )
```

or

```
SELECT user_email
FROM wp_users
WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM wp_usermeta
        WHERE (
                wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_login'
                AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS DATE) BETWEEN '2000-01-06'
                    AND '2016-01-06'
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value As DATE)` before `<= '2016-01-06'`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the criteria before the second date check

```html
Select user_email
from wp_users
where ID in (
        select user_id
        from wp_usermeta
        where (
                wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_login'
                and CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value As DATE) >= '2000-01-06'
                and CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value As DATE) <= '2016-01-06'
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary `and <=`.  You want either `between` or two comparisons:

```
Select user_email
from wp_users u
where ID in (select um.user_id
             from wp_usermeta um
             where um.meta_key = 'last_login' and 
                   CAST(um.meta_value As DATE) >= '2000-01-06' and 
                   CAST(um.meta_value As DATE) <= '2016-01-06'
            );
```

Often, `join`s perform better than `in`.  If `last_login` only appears once per user, you might try:

```
Select u.user_email
from wp_users u join
     wp_usermeta um
     on u.id = um.user_id
where  um.meta_key = 'last_login' and
      CAST(um.meta_value As DATE) >= '2000-01-06' and 
      CAST(um.meta_value As DATE) <= '2016-01-06';
```

Then, if the date is stored as YYYY-MM-DD, then the cast is unnecessary (comparison as strings works):

```
Select u.user_email
from wp_users u join
     wp_usermeta um
     on u.id = um.user_id
where um.meta_key = 'last_login' and
      um.meta_value >= '2000-01-06' and 
      um.meta_value <= '2016-01-06';
```

Finally, this version can take advantage of an index on `wp_usermeta(meta_key, meta_value, user_id)`.